# If-Else Statement-Positive and Negative Integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am just starting my first computer science class and have a question! Here are the exact questions from my class:

"Write a complete python program that allows the user to input 3 integers and outputs yes if all three of the integers are positive and otherwise outputs no.  For example inputs of 1,-1,5. Would output no."

"Write a complete python program that allows the user to input 3 integers and outputs yes if any of  three of the integers is positive and otherwise outputs no.  For example inputs of 1,-1,5. Would output yes."

I started using the if-else statement(hopefully I am on the right track with that), but I am having issues with my output.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if num > 0:
   print("YES")
else:
   print("NO")
```

I have this, but I am not sure where to go with this to get the desired answers. I do not know if I need to add an elif or if I need to tweak something else.

Comment: This isn't really appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific question about why some code isn't working, you can ask a new question, but we're not going to do your homework.

Comment: On lines 1-3 you ask for a number each time, but then line 2 overwrites the input from line 1, and line 3 overwrites the input from line 2 ... so you are not even checking the result of the first two inputs, they are just discarded. You should read about looping, i.e. `while` or `for`.

Comment: @DanLowe That should basically be an (the) answer instead of a comment. As far as this question goes, it's the best answer since it solves the immediate problem without either invoking too-advanced concepts or propsoing fixes in a way that completes the assignment.

Comment: @DanLowe Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, that helps with my problem! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fair enough - posted again as an answer. I hadn't done that before because I usually don't answer "homework" questions, but I see where you're going.

Comment: For the record since a couple of commenters have said something, [homework questions are generally allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/284313) here as long as they're good questions, show effort, etc. Naturally they should be answered with a focus to helping students improve their learning and not just spoon-feeding them complete solutions.

Comment: Look again for.  if and elif methods, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first 3 lines, you collect a number, but always into the same variable (`num`). Since you don't look at the value of `num` in between, the first two collected values are discarded.

You should look into using a loop, e.g. `for n in range(3):`

```py
for n in range(3):
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if num > 0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to create three separate variables like this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter number 3: "))
```

In your code you only keep the value of the last number, as you are always writing to the same variable name :)

From here using an `if else` statement is the correct idea! You should give it a try :) If you get stuck try looking up `and` and `or` keywords in python.

Comment: I know this is a programming 101 class but I want to downvote this so badly for promoting the use of `{num1, num2, num3, ..., numN}` variable name schemes over a list or something similar. Why encourage bad habits?

Comment: The alternative is to use a list. If it is programming 101 he has not gotten to lists yet. I am trying to answer his question using only the code he has provided. Is this a poor approach on SO?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I think it boils down to a question of pedagogy. I personally dislike the idea of teaching students something they simply have to "unlearn" later, but I also understand where you're coming from. Hence why I didn't downvote (but didn't upvote either). ;)